# Como diminuir o tempo de execução utilizando openmp

Tags: c, thread, multithreading, openmp

Eu queria saber o que posso fazer pra diminuir o tempo de execução utilizando as threads do Openmp. Fiz um código pra somar os valores de um vetor de tamanho 2²⁷, porém as medidas de tempo são praticamente iguais quando eu aumento o número de threads... não deveria cair o tempo de execução para cada thread adicionada?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    long int N = pow(2,27);
    long int *vet = malloc(sizeof(long int)*N);
    long int i;
    int nThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    long int soma = 0;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) vet[i] = i;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:soma)
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        soma += vet[i];
    }

    printf("Resultado: %ld\n", soma);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que você não usa uma string para somar esses valores ?, Muito mais simples do que você está fazendo.

Comment: Talvez a parte não paralelizavel esteja tomando o maior tempo de execução. Teste com um vetor menor ou meça somente o tempo da soma. É esperado que com muitas threads não haja ganho real, pois o sistema consome mais recursos só para escalonar as threads e realizar travas.

Comment: não sei, mas quando eu usei não colocava #pragma colocava algo como   #omp parallel for reduction(+:soma)